# something equivalent to implode(php) in Python

Tags: python, join

I've a `dict()` with following `data`

```
{0: 1703554, 1: 1143136, 2: 1877978, 3: 1593739, 4: 708961, 5: 708961, 6: 412752, 7: 266352, 8: 1164387, 9: 1164387}
```

in `PHP` it can be done very easily using `implode()` to get the comma separated list of all the values
like `1703554,1143136,1877978...`
how can I do that using `Python`?
I tried following `print(','.join(str(id)))` and it gave me following output

```
{,0,:, ,1,7,0,3,5,5,4,,, ,1,:, ,1,1,4,3,1,3,6,,, ,2,:, ,1,8,7,7,9,7,8,,, ,3,:, ,1,5,9,3,7,3,9,,, ,4,:, ,7,0,8,9,6,1,,, ,5,:, ,7,0,8,9,6,1,,, ,6,:, ,4,1,2,7,5,2,,, ,7,:, ,2,6,6,3,5,2,,, ,8,:, ,1,1,6,4,3,8,7,,, ,9,:, ,1,1,6,4,3,8,7,}
```

and I've also used `id.values()` but not working, may be I'm using it in wrong way, please help!!!

here is `print(id.values)`

```
[1703554, 1143136, 1877978, 1593739, 708961, 708961, 412752, 266352, 1164387, 1164387]
```

and I want it as `string`

Comment: How did you use `id.values()`? Please post that code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to convert each value to a string and you need to join all those strings with commas:

```
print(','.join(str(v) for v in id.values()))
```

or

```
print(','.join(map(str, id.values())))
```

Comment: but your solution is perfect and very easy to use a new person like me

Comment: I would use the first solution, and instead a generator expression, I'd use a real list, since .join is faster on in-memory lists.

Comment: @ikaros45 that is what is known as premature optimisation. Sure the list may be faster (on a 100 element dictionary I time it about 1.7uS faster which is 8% of the runtime), but unless you have timed it and proved something to be a bottleneck you should prefer the clearer code rather than the faster code.

Comment: I would not call "dirty code" a pair of square brackets :)

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for [`dict.values()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values)

```
>>> d = {0: 1703554, 1: 1143136, 2: 1877978, 3: 1593739, 4: 708961, 5: 708961, 6: 412752, 7: 266352, 8: 1164387, 9: 1164387}
>>> d.values()
[1703554, 1143136, 1877978, 1593739, 708961, 708961, 412752, 266352, 1164387, 1164387]
```

***Edit***

For getting them as a string, you can use a string comprehension:

```
[str(d[key]) for key in d] #or
[str(v) for v in d.values()] #or
[str(value) for _k, value in d.items()]
```

For printing as a string, you can do

```
', '.join(str(v) for v in d.values())
```

Comment: I want string as output

Comment: `[str(x) for x in d.values()]`

Comment: In Python 2 we can replace the last one with `str(d.values())[1:-1]`.(or `str(list(d.values()))[1:-1]` in Python 3)